# Android Widget Stretch/Shrink

Tags: android, resize, widget, cells

I created a little widget for my application. It's 4 cells wide and 1 cell high.
As you can see on the picture, my device has a width of 5 cells. So I would like to support 5x1 too. Same layout, content stretched. How do I do this?

My thougths:
- Do I have to create another widget in size 5x1?
- How to add the functionality to stretch/shrink your widget on the homescreen?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:resizeMode="horizontal"` in your `appwidget-provider`?

Comment: works! How can I show in the widget menu that the widget is also available in 5x1?

Comment: You can't. You'll just have to trust that your users will try to stretch it. If you examine any of the google widgets, you'll see that it'll show a default size, but they'll also be stretchable.

Comment: ok thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `appwidget-provider`, set the resize mode:

```
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ....
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"/>
```